# Regex Value for Line that matches some values

Tags: regex

I have a regex like this: `${BUILD_LOG_REGEX,regex="(?=.*?Environment)(?=.*?Total).*$"}`

The output of this REGEX is like this:

`[...truncated 14 lines...] [java] Environment: XYZ Total(Pass:1 Fail:0 Incomplete:0 Delayed:0 Manual Verification:0) [...truncated 14 lines...]`

I want to modify this regex so i can only See these values as output:

`Environment: XYZ Total(Pass:1 Fail:0 Incomplete:0 Delayed:0 Manual Verification:0)`

Can someone help to find out the correct REGEX for this LINE from the log file?

Comment: What's special about that line? How is it different from the others?

Comment: The special about the 2nd line is... I want to remove extra things which is in between this TAG []... I just want to print the actual line rather then have printed all Junk values like [...truncated 14 lines...] [java].. I don't want this to be printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you might have to be more specific here, since I can match what you are asking for like this:

`E.*?\)`

Link: [Regex101.com Example](http://regex101.com/r/nT6aW2)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**  **This answer specifies a [java](/questions/tagged/java) solution, as the question was originally tagged as a Java question. This tag has since been removed.**

If you're looking to simply remove any text contained inside square brackets, a simple call of the code below will produce the result you are looking for.

```
String source = "[...truncated 14 lines...] [java] Environment: XYZ Total(Pass:1 Fail:0 Incomplete:0 Delayed:0 Manual Verification:0) [...truncated 14 lines...]";
String extract = source.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]", "").trim();
```

Results in `extract` holding the value:

```
"Environment: XYZ Total(Pass:1 Fail:0 Incomplete:0 Delayed:0 Manual Verification:0)"
```

The java code above will replace all occurrences of strings inside square brackets with an empty string (essentially removing them) and then trim any unnecessary whitespace from the result.

Regex:

`\[.*?\]`, where `.*`, with its surrounding square brackets, is lazily (non-greedily) matched.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: I don't want to use JAVA API here... I want a Single REGEX which can do it for me...Currently i have this REGEX --- "(?=.*?Environment)(?=.*?Total).*$" which is printing me this line.....[...truncated 14 lines...] [java] Environment: XYZ Total(Pass:1 Fail:0 Incomplete:0 Delayed:0 Manual Verification:0) [...truncated 14 lines...]... And i want to modify my regex so i can see the output which you used to print it with Replace statement.

Comment: If you do not want to use the Java API, I suggest that in future you do not tag your questions with the [tag:Java] tag. How are you currently executing these regular expressions if not using the Java API?

Comment: This is part of the Jenkins Email features, Where i have build logs and i am trying to Use Jenkins plugin to parse this text using REGEX.

Comment: Have you tried [Vasili Syrakis' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21126393/2081889)?

Comment: Unfortunately, without experience with Jenkins, I'm not in a position to help.